# Can any external hardware / software write something to the cmos motherboard chip?

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard, uefi, cmos

I know there is some software or hardware advertised to be able to read and write what is on cmos chip, but do any normal consumer pieces of hardware or software interact like this with the cmos chip? Would any files be stored on a cmos chip without explicit attempts by the user? (Excluding obvious things like writing windows boot manager to it)

Comment: No, a user mode program running in an operating system is not going to read or write from your CMOS.  `obvious things like writing windows boot manager to it` .. this makes no sense.  The CMOS stores a few things to get your PC firmware going.. it isn't a disk drive or a boot device.

Answer (score 1):

> I know there is some software or hardware advertised to be able to read and write what is on cmos chip,

In principle, every kind of hardware that has access to the system bus as a bus master (like a PCIe card with the right controller) can do that.

Though it's the first time I hear that there is hardware **advertised** for that specifically for the CMOS RAM chip. Do you have any more detailed information or links?

> but do any normal consumer pieces of hardware or software interact like this with the cmos chip?

Nearly all consumer hardware is not interested in looking at the CMOS RAM, **at all**. Nor is it interested in looking at any other installed hardware.

So, no they don't interact like this with anything else.

> Would any files be stored on a cmos chip without explicit attempts by the user?

The CMOS RAM only holds a few bytes of information for the BIOS. It's not big enough to store any files, or anything else beyond that few bytes.